# Go_router current route queryParams

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, flutter-go-router

Using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) :

```
GoRouter.of(context).location
```

gives us the current route path such as `/product/10110` but I'd like to know how to also get the current route queryParams in a similar fashion

*(outside of the GoRoute builder)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now have this functionality.

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String,dynamic> qparams = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.queryParams;

    return const Scaffold(
      body: ...
    );
  }
}
```

This way you can directly access the query params you send using go_router, like:

```
context.goNamed("page", queryParams: {"name": "Addy", "age": "22"}),
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `go_router` has it's `qweryParams` in its state.

*Hence pass the `state` to the page*

---

#### Router

```
 GoRoute(
    name: "test",
    path: "/test",
    builder: (context, state) {
      return SampleWidget(
        goRouterState: state,   Pass state here
      );
    },
  ),
```

#### Usage

```
context.goNamed("test", queryParams: {"email": "example@gmail.com", "age": "25"}),
```

#### Accesing in the page

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  GoRouterState? goRouterState;
  SampleWidget({super.key, this.goRouterState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(goRouterState?.queryParams.toString());  access anywhere like so

    return const Scaffold(
      body: ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, I guess I was more wondering if I could more easily access it through  GoRouter.of(context) but I'm guessing not ! Thanks for your answer I will up vote it :)

Comment: Currently it's not possible using GoRouter.of(context) , so this is the work around